# list is not refreshed in mvc 3 view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have an asp.net view which has two partial views. One for edit information and other one for displaying list of changes that were made. When I hit the update button, the list is not updated. I used ajax.begin form. How can I do this?

Main view has like this:

```
   <div class="accountdetails1">
    @Html.Action("UpdateAccountDetails", new { dispute = dispute })
    </div>

    <div>
    list of changes
    @Html.Action("GetAccountAudit")

    </div>

updateAccountDetails is like this in start:

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("UpdateAccountDetails", new AjaxOptions
{
    LoadingElementId = "loading",
    LoadingElementDuration = 2000,
    OnSuccess = "OnSuccess",
    OnBegin = "OnBegin",
}))
{

and functions are like this:

<script type="text/javascript">
    function OnSuccess() {
        var div = $('#dvMessage');
        div.html('');
        div.append('Account Information has been updated.');
    }

    function OnBegin() {
        var div = $('#dvMessage');
        div.html('');
    }
</script>
```

to show success or failure of update Do I need to update change list in success method? Please suggest

Comment: do you have a div with the id of dvMessage?

Comment: yes. it shows message but is not for list, it is for success message. @Html.Action("GetAccountAudit") is not in this dvMessage

Comment: @Html.Action(...) is not a partial view. It actually makes an additional request to your server.

Comment: @Dismissile: How to do it then

Comment: How to do what? If you want to display a partial view then just use @Html.Partial(...). I was just stating that these two things are very different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ajax methods works in following way:

@Ajax.ActionLink - requests HTML from pointed action via AJAX and puts result in HTML element with id equals to UpdateTargetId value specified in AjaxOptions.

@Ajax.BeginForm - gets the all inputs and selects and other form elements inside using(Ajax.BeginForm()) { .. } and submits it to specified action (using AJAX) then puts response to HTML element with id specified in AjaxOptions.UpdateTargetId property.

So you need something like

```
<div id="myContainer" >
@using(Ajax.BeginForm("yourActionToProcessEdits", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "myContainer" }))
{
.. Form for edit information
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.EditMe)
...

<input type="submit" value="Update" />

.. Display changes here
@Html.Raw(Model.MyChanges)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to request the GetAccountAudit action to return the list.  The beginform is only requesting the UpdateAccountDetails action.

You could do a jquery ajax request in the onSuccess function to request the GetAccountAudit action and update the html.

Could the two actions be combined so that the list would be returned in the UpdateAccountDetails view?

Comment: any sample link or code sample please. I am newbie to jquery ajax with MVC